# Batch file: How to play with loops and creating new directories

Tags: loops, batch-file, cmd, directory, command-line-arguments

I can't find the solution.
I made the directory to be generated, with the approach that if it exists, create another one with -1, -2 ... added to the name of the directory.
But I can't get it to continue exporting the loop from MP4list and export it differently in the other directories.

Below I will explain the batch file in great detail, maybe someone has a solution how to approach the situation:

**First try**

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "musicdir=MUZICA-wav-mp3"  
set "exportfoldername=Canal"
set "exportdir=Export\%exportfoldername%
set "videodir=Video-15-sec"  

set n=0
md "%exportdir%"||call :a %n%


<"mp4list.txt" (
    for %%A in ("%musicdir%\*") DO (
        set /p mp4list=
        ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i "!mp4list!" -c copy mergedmp4.mp4
        ffmpeg -i mergedmp4.mp4 -i "%%A" -map 0:v -map 1:a -vcodec copy -c:a aac -b:a 320k "%exportdir%-%n%\%%~nA.mp4"
        del mergedmp4.mp4"
    )
)   

exit
:a
set /a n+=1
md "%exportdir%-%n%"||goto a
exit /b
```

For my second try I used `for /f "skip=`

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "musicdir=D:\MONTAJ VIDEO\video-simplu\MUZICA-wav-mp3"  

 

set "exportdir=D:\MONTAJ VIDEO\video-simplu\Export\canal-1
set "exportdir2=D:\MONTAJ VIDEO\video-simplu\Export\canal-2
set "exportdir3=D:\MONTAJ VIDEO\video-simplu\Export\canal-3
set "videodir=D:\LUCRU-VIDEO\Video-15-sec"  



rem ==============  Canal-1

for /f "skip=1" %%G IN (mp4list.txt) DO if not defined line set "line=%%G"

for %%A in ("%musicdir%\*") DO (
        mkdir "%exportdir%" 
        
        echo %line%
        ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i "%line%" -c copy mergedmp4.mp4
    ffmpeg -i mergedmp4.mp4 -i "%%A" -map 0:v -map 1:a -vcodec copy -c:a aac -b:a 320k "%exportdir%\%%~nA.mp4"
        del mergedmp4.mp4"
    )


rem ==============  Canal-2
for /f "skip=3" %%G IN (mp4list.txt) DO if not defined line set "line2=%%G"
 

for %%A in ("%musicdir%\*") DO (
        mkdir "%exportdir2%"
        echo %line2%
        ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i "%line2%" -c copy mergedmp4.mp4
    ffmpeg -i mergedmp4.mp4 -i "%%A" -map 0:v -map 1:a -vcodec copy -c:a aac -b:a 320k "%exportdir2%\%%~nA.mp4"
        del mergedmp4.mp4"
    )


rem ==============  Canal-3
for /f "skip=5" %%G IN (mp4list.txt) DO if not defined line set "line3=%%G"

for %%A in ("%musicdir%\*") DO (
        mkdir "%exportdir3%"
       echo %line3%
        ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i "%line3%" -c copy mergedmp4.mp4
    ffmpeg -i mergedmp4.mp4 -i "%%A" -map 0:v -map 1:a -vcodec copy -c:a aac -b:a 320k "%exportdir3%\%%~nA.mp4"
        del mergedmp4.mp4"
    )
```

I really don't know in what direction to go...

Let's say I have 5 songs in the directory  `musicdir` and 100 lines with different .mp4 paths in `mp4list.txt` , 100 directories with the same 5 songs in each directory should be created. `Canal-1`, `Canal-2` ... `Canal-100`

When all songs in  `musicdir` are exported in `Canal-1`  the loop will start again with the same songs from  `musicdir`, with the difference that .mp4 videos will be exported in the next folder `Canal-2` and so on.

but it is **very important** that the loop continues in the file `mp4list.txt`and continue where it left off in the previous directory in order not to repeat the same mp4 files

`mp4list.txt` contains the path's of mp4 files, all are unique

even if from `musicdir` it will start from the beginning with exporting mp4 files in a new directory, in `mp4list.txt` it will continue where it left off in the previous directory

Batch will finish when all lines in `mp4list.txt`   are finished.

`mp4list.txt`  is like this

```
output.txt
output1.txt
...
output100.txt
```

and every `output.txt`  have the path to mp4 file.
like this

```
file '1.mp4'
file '2.mp4'
file '3.mp4'
file '4.mp4'
```

thank you for your help

Comment: You seem to have posted a lot of information about your task, examples of the source files read from a text file, and example content from those. You've also posted your code, which is also good. However your question does not explain to us any problem with that code, or how it may be failing to meet your task requirements. You have specifically asked for help to improve it, but not indicated what you mean by improvement. Without that information the assumption will be that you just want us to code your task for you, as a free service, so that you can swap yours for ours. That's not on topic.

Comment: @Compo I edited the question and wrote what doesn't work in my batch. you're right, but because  I'm not a native English speaker, I did the translation from my language... and it seems that it's not clear that my batch doesn't work.

Comment: @compo I also added a second try using ``` for /f "skip=n```  . really i need a direction.. :(